# How to calculate each load current in a 3-wires split-phase system

Tags: current, split-phase

In a 3-wires split-phase system, if I take current readings from two hot wires L1(IL1), L2(IL2) and Neutral (IN). Is it possible find out the amount of current flow to each of loads, as shown in following figure:

[image]

Find the current values of Ia, Ib and Ic, where the impedance(resistance) of LOADs are unknown.

Answer (score 2):

No it is not possible to calculate Ia,Ib and Ic from IL1,IL2 and IN

E.g. If load A and Load B are equal then you have Il1=IL2 and IN=0. If Load C has a high impedance or is even removed then Ic is small or zero. If Load C has a small impedance then the Ic his high. Still IL1=Il2 and IN=0. So you can not find out how the flows over load A and load B and the current that flows over load C divides.